# javascript: prototyping with multiple objects

Tags: javascript, namespaces, prototyping

Sorry if this is answered somewhere (it probably is), but I'm not quite sure how to even ask it properly, so I failed at searching :(

Basically I want to do something like this:

```
(a||b).prototype.c = function () {
  // do something
}
```

Basically a and b are objects. One or the other will exist, but not both.  But I don't know which will exist, but I need to add a method to whichever one does.

Now, I know I could do something like this:

```
if (typeof(a) == 'object') {
  a.prototype.c = c;
} else if (typeof(b) == 'object') {
  b.prototype.c = c;
} 

function c () {
  // do something
}
```

But this has the problem of c having its own namespace on the global level, and I don't want that. I do not want c to have it's own namespace on the global level at any point in time.

Soo...obviously the first bit of code above doesn't work.  How would I go about this? Or is something like this simply not possible? Please feel free to close and point me in the right direction if this has been answered before...

Comment: actually, I think my first thing does work, if I remove the prototype part, because I'm adding c to an instantiated object, not prototyping a class, right?

Comment: Kind of, prototype is for accessing the type of the object, skip it, and you access the actual object.

Comment: yeah I'm working with 2 actual objects, so I think I actually shouldn't be prototyping at all.  Apparently (a||b).c = function () { .. } does indeed work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this will solve your problem:

```
(function() {
  var f = function() {
    //Prototype function
  };
  if(a)
    a.prototype.f = f;
  if(b)
    b.prototype.f = f;
})();
```

Comment: hmm yeah, I think this should work if I were wanting to do that, but I think in truth I don't need to prototype at all, since I'm trying to add a method to either one instantiated object or another.  But I was nonetheless curious how I would go about prototyping on one class or the other and I'm gonna mark because this does answer that question, thanks!